# How to Write a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I've a string

```
SUM(Latest#3)
```

I've written a regular expresson as :-

```
(?:\((?<n>[^\#]+)\#(?<v>[^\)]+)\))
```

The result is Fine :-

```
n:Latest
v:3
```

but when I am changing the expression to :-

```
Sqrt(Sum(Latest#3))
```

The value is getting changed to :-

```
n: sum(Latest)
v: 3
```

I want this expression to check upto last occurence of `(` i.e. the desired output of above expression `(Sqrt(Sum(Latest#3)))` should be like :-

```
n:Latest
v:[3]
```

Please help as I am new to reqular expressions.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: I believe your title can be better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `(` to the negated character class:

```
(?:\((?<n>[^(#]+)#(?<v>[^)]+)\))
```

Also, no need to escape `(`,  `)` or `#` inside character classes.

For your more complex example from your comment, you could do this: Search for

```
(?:\((?<n>[^(#]+)#(?<v>[^,]+)(?<r>,[^)]*)\))
```

and replace with

```
([${n}#${v}]${r})
```

(you might need to change `${n}` to whatever syntax Expresso uses for named backreferences.

Comment: One more question on above question itself If I am changing the expression to:-(Sqrt(Sum(Latest#3,Last))) The result is n:Latest v:3,Last. Can we somehow restrict the vlaue of v as v:3, because I am unable to restrict the search upto occerance of ","

Comment: Why not?  Can't you say `[^),]+`? What *can* you restrict the search to? If only letters/digits are allowed, you could use `\w+` instead of `[^)]+`.

Comment: Tim I am trying to use the suggestion provided by you, but unfortunately not getting the specific result.Could you please help me If I am having expression as :-  Sum(First#5,ABC.XYZ)+SQRT(Sum(Last#8,DEF.IJK)) and I want to convert it to :- 
Sum([First#5],ABC.XYZ)+SQRT(Sum([Last#8],DEF.IJK)) I've spend nearly a complete day figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

To handle nested brackets you need to use the following regex:

`(?:\((?<n>[^\#(]+)\#(?<v>[^\)]+)\))`

Comment: One more question on above question itself If I am changing the expression to:-(Sqrt(Sum(Latest#3,Last))) The result is n:Latest v:3,Last. Can we somehow restrict the vlaue of v as v:3, because I am unable to restrict the search upto occerance of ","